# Python: Return a blank and continue for loop after exception

Tags: python, exception

I have a for loop where I'm using an API key to return some values into a CSV. I want the loop to return a blank row every time there's an error rather than the code breaking. I know I need to use a `continue` but not sure how to insert a blank row for every `indexError` I get.

I've written a function called `get_data` that returns the response text from the API. So using that, this is what I'm trying to run for an input file `df`

```
d = []
try: 
    for i in range(len(df)):
        output = df.loc[i,"column_1"] 
        d.append(get_data(output))
        lat = pd.DataFrame(d)
        lat_lon= lat.apply(pd.Series)
        f = open('results.csv','w')
        lat_lon.to_csv('results.csv')
except IndexError: 
        print('ERROR at index {}: {!r}'.format(i, address))
```

I want the output csv file `results.csv` to leave a blank row every time there was an `indexError`

Answer (score 1):

`try/except` needs to be inside the loop. Otherwise you abort the entire loop when the exception occurs.

Also, you shouldn't write the CSV file every time through the loop. Write it at the end with the complete contents of `d`.

```
d = []
for i in range(len(df)):
    try: 
        output = df.loc[i,"column_1"] 
        d.append(get_data(output))
    except IndexError: 
        print('ERROR at index {}: {!r}'.format(i, address))
        d.append([default row goes here])
lat = pd.DataFrame(d)
lat_lon= lat.apply(pd.Series)
f = open('results.csv','w')
lat_lon.to_csv('results.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks! But confused as to what  `d.append([default row goes here])` is doing

Comment: I don't know how many elements the list is supposed to have. So I just put that as a placeholder, you can replace it with a list containing the proper number of empty strings.

Comment: Ahh gotcha! Thank you, this was very helpful